# HERE Maps API for JavaScript v3.1: adding event listener "tap" to domMarker doesn't work on android devices

Tags: here-api, heremaps

I'm using latest version for HERE Maps API for JavaScript (v3.1) and when trying to add an event listener "tap" to domMarker doesn't work on android devices. With 'click' event it works on IOS devices but also doesn't work for android devices. Can you help me with that please?
Thank you!

I was expecting that with the 'tap' it would work for both android and IOS devices but it doesn't trigger the event.

Here is the code:

```
    addMarkersModal (map,points:Array<Points>,pos:PointsCoordinates) {
        const group = new H.map.Group();
        const objects = [];
    
        map.addObject(group);
    
        // Add markers around the target position.
        for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
          objects.push(this.addDOMMarker(points[i].address.coordinates.latitude, points[i].address.coordinates.longitude, points[i]._id, 'typePoint'));
        }
    
        group.addObjects(objects);
        map.addObject(group);
    
        this.setViewBoundsFitAllMarkers(map, objects, pos, this.boundingMarkersMargin);
        return map;   
}
    
addDOMMarker(lat: number, lng: number, id: string, type: string) {
        const wrapperElement = document.createElement('div'), 
        markerElement = document.createElement('div');
        wrapperElement.className = 'marker-wrapper';
        markerElement.className = 'marker ' + type;
        markerElement.id = 'marker-' + id;
    
        wrapperElement.appendChild(markerElement);
    
        const domIcon = new H.map.DomIcon(wrapperElement, {
          onAttach: (clonedElement: any) => {
            clonedElement.addEventListener('tap', (evt) => {
              this.selectMarker(id, false);
              evt.stopPropagation();
            });
          }
        });
    
        return new H.map.DomMarker({lat: lat, lng: lng}, {icon: domIcon});  
 }
```